# JavaFX get data out of a tableview into a textfield

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I will edit my columns but I don't know how to do it.
I need to know how I get the selected row data in a text field

I'm learning java but I don't know how to do it.

You can see it on the screen

```
 public void Showeditscreen () {
        Stage editstage = new Stage();

        VBox editbox = new VBox(8);
        editbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        editbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label editlabel = new Label("Edit persondetails");

        TextField editfirstnameinput = new TextField();


        TextField editlastnameinput = new TextField();

        TextField editemailinput = new TextField();
```

[image]

Comment: You can get the item in the selected row using `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`. Then just call methods that give you the appropriate properties. Without seeing more details about how your table is set up and how your model class is defined, it's hard to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
YourObject yourObject = yourTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
TextField editfirstnameinput = new TextField();
editfirstnameinput.setText(yourObject.getFirstName());
TextField editlastnameinput = new TextField();
editlastnameinput.setText(yourObject.getLastName());
TextField editemailinput = new TextField();
editemailinput.setText(yourObject.getEmail());
```